# Introducing a middle base class causes ActiveMQ/JMS NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

Currently I have an application that sends a JMS `ObjectMessage` to an ActiveMQ destination. The messages are all derived from class `base`.

However, I needed to add a class between certain derived classes and the base class, so class `middle` extends `base`. Now, all the messages that extends `middle` fail to send, giving the following error:

```
26 18:53:04.524 [ListenerContainer-1] WARN  - Execution of JMS message listener failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ProtocolMessageEnum
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
```

The messages that do not extend middle work still, only the messages that derives from `middle` now cause the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: The sending is handled by `session.createObjectMessage(msg)` where `msg` is of type `base`.

Comment: Are you sending a JMS `ObjectMessage`?

Comment: Yes. The sending is handled by ```session.createObjectMessage(msg)```, where msg is of type base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you're sending a JMS `ObjectMessage` it looks to me like your client simply doesn't have the proper classes on the classpath to deserialize the message. Ensure the clients have the "middle" class and any new parameter types on their classpath. At the very least they'll need `com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum` (as indicated by the exception).

For what it's worth, JMS `ObjectMessage` is often avoided for this and other reasons. It's usually simpler to send raw byte buffers or some simple object representation (e.g. XML, JSON, etc.) rather than actual Java objects. Also, Java serialization and deserialization are notoriously slow and this pattern can open your application to security vulnerabilities as well.

Comment: Hi, so I found the solution to the issue. Certain start scripts were missing the protobuf.jar that they needed. The issue had nothing to do with the middle class. Apparently, it was already not working and I thought that introducing the middle class caused the issue, when the issue was already present. Due to this, I didn't think that a missing jar was the issue.